# Checking size of string before operation with fscanf?

Tags: c

I'm attempting to write a safe file input. I have a fixed buffer size of 128. I want to read the strings from the file, but before copying them I want to check they are less than or equal to `128` in length.

Can I do something like:

```
fscanf(fp, "%128s", myString)
```

I've seen that scanf used in the same way will limit the number of characters read in but not seen any reference to it been used that way with fscanf and strings?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What's wrong with the code in the question?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/ width is mentioned in the reference.

Comment: Basically everything `scanf` does, `fscanf` does.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit What are you talking about?  `Those listed here are supported by the latest C` Next time check the link you are criticizing.

Comment: @Armin: Prefer an authoritative C reference. cplusplus.com is notoriously inaccurate for C++ and I dread to think how well it covers C

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I read it all and had no problems. What do you recommend instead?

Comment: @Armin: For C++? http://cppreference.com. For C? No idea. Just because you read it doesn't mean it's right. It is likely that you now hold fundamental misconceptions about C++ without even knowing it, which is a great shame... especially if you're to go on to spread those misconceptions on the internet.

Comment: I never said it is right because i read it. :) All i said was, that i read it and thus far it was correct so don't make assumptions please. Also this is C im talking about so i don't know where your going with your shame and misconceptions and c++ :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do that but you're off by 1. 
So if you have an array of 128 characters in length:

```
char myString[128] = {'\0'};
fscanf(fp, %127s", myString);
```

You mentioned that you've seen that syntax used in `scanf()`, well that's the same thing as:

```
fscanf(stdin, "%127s", myString); // just like scanf("%127s", myString);
```

Note how the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) has the same information regarding the format string for `scanf()` and `fscanf()`

Answer (score 2):

If you're on the windows platform I think you can use `fscanf_s` otherwise I think it's better to use `fgets` and/or `sscanf` :)

Answer (score 2):

you can use [`char * fgets ( char * str, int num, FILE * stream );`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) to avoid buffer overrun

like:

```
fgets(myString, 127, fp);
```

Comment: Off by one. For a buffer of 128 characters, you can have 127 characters and '\0'. Calling `fgets(myString, 128, fp)` reads 127 characters and appends the '\0'. `The functions fgets() reads up to n-1 characters from the input stream referenced by fp. It copies the read string into the buffer buf, appending a null character to terminate the string.` http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_file_io.htm